# How to get @session.get("loginUserName") data inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

I have a simple logout button which calls a logout($event) function via angular directive ng-click. There is a dynamic label @session which I don't understand how to call from my angular service.

```
<a ng-href='#' ng-click='logout($event)'><font size="2"><u>Logout, @session.get("loginUserName")</u></font></a>
```

It looks like this on the website: "Logout, myUserName"

This is from my angular service code:

```
var service = {
  getUserName: function(){
    return @session.get("loginUserName");
  }

return service;
```

The @session expression of course returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

How can I access this @session.get("loginUserName") from my angular code?

Comment: Try with `@session.get("loginUserName")`, However `@session`  comes from which language?

Comment: I don't know, unfortunately